# How to change the torrent file name to the file/folder it's downloading?

Tags: windows, bittorrent

For example, there is a torrent named: 1894515619841.torrent and the file it's downloading is called "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" so what I would like to do is change that 1894515619841.torrent to xxxxxxxxxxxxx.torrent, this won't be an issue if there was only one torrent file, but I have dozens of them so it's quite hard. So I'm looking for a bulk utility that it can be used to perform such action

I know that I can download from other places that have the same file, but I'm downloading from a private tracker and it has more torrent than the free torrent sites.

Comment: Try : https://sourceforge.net/projects/dumptorrent/

Comment: Yea but dumptorrent only shows info about the torrent and doesn't modify the name.

Comment: Have you figured it out or still looking for help ?

Comment: Have you figured it out or still looking for help ?